# Cordova badge update - Android

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

Using Angular for my mobile app, I have this code for notification received -

```
$scope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function (event, notification) {
    handleAndroid(notification);
});
```

which calls

```
function handleAndroid(notification) {
         if (notification.event == "message") {
            $cordovaBadge.increase();
        }
        else if (notification.event == "error")
            $cordovaDialogs.alert(notification.msg, "Push notification error event");
        else $cordovaDialogs.alert(notification.event, "Push notification handler - Unprocessed Event");
    }
```

When I trigger this notification outside of my mobile app, with the app closed, I'd expect :

1. Badge increments
2. User gets notification in banner at the top.

However what happens is:

1. User gets notification in banner at the top
2. Click on the banner,which opens the app.
3. When app is moved to the background, badge increments.

How do I get the badge to increment as soon as the notification is received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens in your case is when you open the app by clicking on the banner your handler executes and the badge number increases. However AFAIK when your app is closed you don't have any chance to run JS code therefore you cannot increase the badge number programmatically.

Comment: Do I need to have my app run some polling function to check every so often for updates to the badge?

Comment: the plugin is created to show that there is a notification for the app but it can't know how many unread item are there in your app, so you might indeed need to run some polling if it's ever possible.